# How can we apply differential equations to optics.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Differential equations in itself is a very complex topic. I read this article on a website that we can apply differential equations to optics and something like brachistochrone problem. What is this brachistochrone problem?

Comment: [Google](http://tinyurl.com/beaqv2f) is your friend. Also, you should read about the [Eikonal Equation](http://tinyurl.com/a4j35gk)

Comment: You are aware of Maxwell's equations, by any chance?